# why are my react components rendering in a horizontal direction instead of rendering vertically?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render my counter component multiple times in another component called 'counters' but when I render it is rendering in horizontal fashion but in the tutorial I am following it is rendering in vertical fashion.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Counter from './counter';
class Counters extends Component {
    
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <Counter/>
                <Counter/>
                <Counter/>
                <Counter/>
            </div>
          
         );
    }
}
 
export default Counters;
```

here is the counter code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
   state={
       count:0,
       tags:["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
   };

   handleIncrement=product=>{
       console.log(product)
       this.setState({count:this.state.count +1})
   }
    render() { 

        
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleIncrement("Mobile Phone")}className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-3">Increment</button>
           
        </React.Fragment>
          );

         
    }
    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += (this.state.count) === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

     formatCount(){

              return this.state.count===0?"Zero":this.state.count;
          }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please show the `Counter` code, and also any CSS rules you might have.

Comment: I have now added counter code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Just change `<React.Fragment>` to `<div>`

```
  <div>
    <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleIncrement("Mobile Phone")} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-3">Increment</button>             
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you elaborate why did this happen ?

Comment: Because div has `div style => { display: block; }` attached to it by default. It makes every div to come in new line. React.Fragment does not have this style.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following styles to view it vertically:

```
   <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
      <Counter />
    </div>
```